# How can i fix error in if-statement Python without elif

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing a simple Python program that defines the age category by number. For example, 15 is a teenager. But the program when you enter 13 gives both childhood and teenager.

```
age = int(input())
if age <= 13:
    print("childhood")
if age >= 13 <= 24:
    print("teenager")
if age >= 25 <= 59:
    print("adult")
if age >= 59:
    print("old age")
```

How can I fix this without using elif?

Comment: Why would you not want to use elif?

Comment: What do you think `<=` means? What do you think `>=` means? If you do `13 <= 13`, what result do you expect? If you do `13 >= 13`, what result do you expect? Do you see the problem?

Comment: One advantage of `elif` is efficiency. Even with your code working correctly, it's always going to check *all* of those conditions, every time. Why keep checking things once you find a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used you made both conditions true as 13 fits both conditions as you don't need to use less/greater than or equal for them both `13 <= 13` and `13 >= 13` so it satisfies them both.

Do this:

```
age = int(input())
if age < 13:
    print("childhood")
if age >= 13 and age < 24:
    print("teenager")
if age >= 25 and age < 59:
    print("adult")
if age >= 59:
    print("old age")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first if statement to "<" instead of "<=" or change the second if statement to ">" instead of ">=". Presumably the former if you want 13 year olds to be teenagers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use else if, but that is **very** clunky, as you need an indent every time you elif.

```
if True:
    print()
else:
    if True:
        print()
    else:
        if True:
            print()
        else:
            print()
```